# Since upgrade to kernel version > 5.11.0.40 - powerlight remains on after shutdown

Tags: 20.04, kernel, shutdown

Lenovo V145-15AST - using 20.04 since initial release, no shutdown problems, however Realtek 8821-CE wireless adapter only started working since kernel version > 5.11.0.

Since upgrading from 5.11.0.40 to 5.11.0.41 (and subsequent versions, currently 5.11.44), after shutdown (either from command line `shutdown -h now` or via desktop menu), the power light remains on. Pressing the power button for > 5 secs will switch it off).

The consequences are;

1. I can not tell if the machine has halted.
2. I can not just press the power button to switch it on, I must press > 5 secs, then power on.

Where is the place (forum/issue tracker) to notify Ubuntu developers about this problem?

Comment: Bugtracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu Can you boot again to the 5.11.0.40 to confirm the problem is not occurring with that kernel? After pressing Power, is your system in the "sleep" state? Does the powerlight go off if you fully shut down?

Comment: Yes, I have pinned to 5.11.0.40 (so it will not be removed) and have tested each kernel upgrade since, today I can confirm problem exists in 5.11.0.44 5.11.0.40 works fine.

Comment: It has been [reported on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1956467) Make that comment an answer then I can mark this as solved. Thank you.